# how can I manage errors in login built in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a doubt about my code. I am trying to redirect erros if account is disable , and invalid cred ,but my code is doing if its invalid doesn't do nothing , but I want to send json data like `invalid credentials` however it doesnt going to anywhere from my conditions

Views.py

```
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'login.html', { 'form':  AuthenticationForm })

    def post(self, request):
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                request,
                username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            )

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/') # home page
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("A") # account disabled
            else:
                return HttpResponse("invalid_creds")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
  path('profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
  path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

]
```

settings

```
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/profile'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

html

```
 <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
        <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email" /></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
        <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button></div><a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try moving the "return HttpResponse("invalid_creds")" one level higher so it is returned on invalid form:

Edit: Changed the method a bit, as per coment.

```
def LoginView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                request,
                username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            )

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/') # home page
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("A") # account disabled
        else: # this else is one level higher
                return HttpResponse("invalid_creds")

    return render(request, 'login.html', { 'form':  AuthenticationForm })
```

Comment: it keeps the same . it only redirect in login.html

Comment: the same ,but it seems using `{{ form }}` alone it works the validation , is there way to overwrite it ?